# How to assign to column with non-string "name" or index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Pandas' DataFrames have a method `assign` which will assign values to a column, and which differs from methods like `loc` or `iloc` in that it returns a DataFrame with the newly assigned column(s) without modifying any shallow copies or references to the same data.

The `assign` method uses argument names to denote column names (or "index" in pandas parlance), and it works fine if one is dealing with column names that are strings, but pandas supports usage of arbitrary python objects as column names.

Suppose I have a DataFrame with integers as column "names":

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    0 : [1,2,3],
    1 : [4,5,6]
})
```

How can I assign, say, to the column `0`?

This doesn't work:

```py
df.assign(0 = df[[0]]+1)
```

```
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
```

Nor does this:

```py
df.assign(**{0:df[[0]]+1})
```

```
TypeError: keywords must be strings
```

Now, I could use direct assign or `loc`, but it would modify the underlying data - for example:

```py
df_shallow_copy = df
df[[0]] = df[[0]] + 1
```

Now `df_shallow_copy` would have values `[2,3,4]` for column `0` instead of `[1,2,3]`.

I could also do a full deep copy of all the columns, but that involves duplicating the data in memory and performing redundant operations:

```py
df_shallow_copy = df
df = df.copy()
df[[0]] = df[[0]] + 1
```

How can I assign to the column without generating a redundant deep copy and without potentially modifying other objects?

Comment: In what sense does `assign` not deep copy, is it some kind of copy on write behind the scenes?

Comment: I was thinking it would be (at least the docs give that impression), in the same way as e.g. R's `data.table` or `dplyr`, but `assign` actually just ends up doing a full deep copy behind the scenes: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/4bfe3d07b4858144c219b9346329027024102ab6/pandas/core/frame.py#L4509

Comment: Great, now we know. I do miss copy on write - i.e shallow copy with deep copy semantics or so

Answer (score 1):

You could side-step the integer keyword problem with a rename like this:

```
df.rename(columns={0:'tmp'}).assign(tmp=lambda x: x['tmp']+1).rename(columns={'tmp':0})

   0  1
0  2  4
1  3  5
2  4  6
```

Would that work for your use-case?

Comment: Thanks. I guess this is an appropriate solution, but if this were to be used in some general-purpose code, it'd have to first make sure to use a name that's not already in the DataFrame. Wonder if there's some more elegant alternative that would still retain the efficiency without having to come up with a unique name...

Comment: You could generate a random temporary column name - like a 30 (or whatever) character alphanumeric string - that *almost* ensured that it would not exist in the DF.  Though would still agree that that would be kind of hackish and not elegant.

Comment: @anymous.asker In what you are doing would there be any location consistency in the DF columns you are working with such that you could leverage `iloc`?

Comment: yes, but how would you do it with `iloc` without creating a copy?

Comment: @anymous.asker Now that is an interesting question.  It seems plausible to me that `iloc` could potentially not make a copy if it were a full-column slice.  I was looking in pandas source to confirm or deny that hypothesis but couldn't find it.  Do you know for sure that `iloc` always makes a copy?

Comment: Not sure, but from some testing it looks it does: `df.iloc[list(range(df.shape[0])), 0] = df[0] + 1` -> modifies shallow copies elsewhere.

Comment: @anymous.asker This modifies the original DF:  `df.iloc[:, 0] = df[0] + 1` . But I think that is not applicable since we are probably talking about `__setitem__` there and really we would be working with `__getitem__` I think for your use case.  Not sure how to determine if a copy is made in that case.  Like for `tmp=df.iloc[:, 0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most straightforward way, but you could use:

```
df.pipe(lambda d: d[[0]].add(1).combine_first(d))
```

output:

```
   0  1
0  2  4
1  3  5
2  4  6
```

Comment: This would produce the right solution, but it is a rather inefficient way as it will have to iterate over every value in every column to see if it is missing.

Comment: @anymous.asker why? You don't need to check anything. There is no iteration required here. What is your use case?

Comment: I mean, the method that's called here (`combine_first`) will check every value in every column: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/4bfe3d07b4858144c219b9346329027024102ab6/pandas/core/frame.py#L7426

The use case here is to pre-process objects inside a statistical modeling package.

Comment: I see, yes combine first will replace the whole data. Efficiency will depend on your dataset size